# My new created API is not working when i am restarting the server

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I am restarting the server, my new created APIs stops working and giving me "Can not POST" error on Postman.
But when I am hitting some older API, then my new APIs starts working.
Example, `getAllPaymentDetails` is already existing API and I have created one API named `create-payment-intent`.

So now when I am restarting the server, `create-payment-intent` is not working and giving "can not post" error, then I have to hit `getAllPaymentDetails` (or any other older APIs) and then `create-payment-intent starts` working.

error:

> Cannot POST /payment/create-payment-intent

Next time its giving expected response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "response": {
    "clientSecret": "pi_3LL4ixSIj3b4yMU7_secret_4MJvyA39NRp80zDi"
  }
}
```

I don't know what's causing this error.
Also, on my test environment, it is working one time and not working another time (working one time of two times).

What can be possible issue?

Comment: As a friendly reminder, I recommend not sharing clientSecrets or secret keys in public forums. https://stripe.com/docs/keys#safe-keys

Comment: that is not correct secret i have shared.

Comment: please show how your loading routes, sounds like your assigning the new routes in the old ones

Comment: app.use('/payment', require('./controller/user-payment-controller')); like this its used in server.js file.
I am adding one route in user-payment-controller.js file and calling one function which i created in user-payment-service.js file.

Comment: my API is working now by moving all my new APIs to new controller file. In that controller, when i am adding any new API, its not working properly, moving it to other controller solved the problem, but still i want to know why it was not working when it was kept in older controller.